# How to update a shell script from within itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, exec

I would like to implement an auto-updater in a shell script. This script would update itself first, then it would go on with the rest of updates.

I believe this is possible using the `exec` command in Linux, but it seems to me that this is just calling a new script and not stopping the termination of the old one.

Can you tell me why do I have an error in the following scenario.

**exectestA.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "a1"
sleep 1
cp exectestB.sh exectest.sh
echo "a2"
sleep 1
exec ./exectest.sh
echo "a3"
sleep 1
```

**exectestB.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "b1"
sleep 1
echo "b2"
sleep 1
cp exectestA.sh exectest.sh
echo "b3"
sleep 1
```

**start command**

```
cp exectestA.sh exectest.sh
./exectest.sh
```

**output on my machine**

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
./exectest.sh: 13: ./exectest.sh: ho: not found
```

If the cp isn't present in exectestB there are no problems (it terminates after b3).

Although I understand that for a normal update process the cp in B shouldn't be needed, I would like to understand why including cp in B results in an error to avoid possible bugs in the future.

At the moment, it seems to me that execA keeps running after it called execB. Is this the case, and if so how can I avoid it?

Note: it seems to depend on the length of the B script. The outcome changes if I insert empty lines at the beginning of the B script.

Comment: Avoid updating the current shell script....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing is certainly not guaranteed, particularly since you have `/bin/sh` in the shebang line. On some systems, `/bin/sh` is *not* bash, and may not behave in the same way.

`bash` attempts to deal with self-modifying scripts by remembering the current position in the scriptfile before executing a command, and seeking back to that position before reading the next command. (Roughly speaking. The code is a bit more complicated and there are a *lot* of corner cases. And it won't work if the scriptfile is not a real file, so that seeking is impossible.) So after you overwrite the executing script file, execution will continue at the same character offset in the new file. In order for this to be meaningful, you have to make sure that the new file has exactly the same prefix (or at least, a prefix of exactly the same length) as the old file.

It is possible to do an update without relying on bash internals, by doing the `cp` and the `exec` in the same command:

```
cp exectestB.sh exectest.sh && exec ./exectest.sh
```

Remember that `exec` never returns, so the next command (if there is one) will only be executed if either the `cp` or the `exec` failed.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that it is indeed related to bash vs. dash. This test case behaves very differently on dash vs. bash.
http://pastie.org/8804637

Answer (score 2):

exectestB.sh is overriding itself (it is exectest.sh when it is executed) with the copy command. This is not possible. The script continues to be read. exectestA.sh should execute the command 'echo', but because of the character offset 'ho' is read, which is not a command.

Answer (score 1):

In case it would help out anyone, here is how I did this.  It executes the existing script if it is unable to download a new one, else it replaces itself with the downloaded one and executes that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
set -fb

readonly THISDIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd)
readonly MY_NAME=$(basename "$0")
readonly FILE_TO_FETCH_URL="https://your_url_to_downloadable_file_here"
readonly EXISTING_SHELL_SCRIPT="${THISDIR}/somescript.sh"
readonly EXECUTABLE_SHELL_SCRIPT="${THISDIR}/.somescript.sh"

function get_remote_file() {
  readonly REQUEST_URL=$1
  readonly OUTPUT_FILENAME=$2
  readonly TEMP_FILE="${THISDIR}/tmp.file"
  if [ -n "$(which wget)" ]; then
    $(wget -O "${TEMP_FILE}"  "$REQUEST_URL" 2>&1)
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      mv "${TEMP_FILE}" "${OUTPUT_FILENAME}"
      chmod 755 "${OUTPUT_FILENAME}"
    else
      return 1
    fi
  fi
}
function clean_up() {
  # clean up code (if required) that has to execute every time here
}
function self_clean_up() {
  rm -f "${EXECUTABLE_SHELL_SCRIPT}"
}

function update_self_and_invoke() {
  get_remote_file "${FILE_TO_FETCH_URL}" "${EXECUTABLE_SHELL_SCRIPT}"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    cp "${EXISTING_SHELL_SCRIPT}" "${EXECUTABLE_SHELL_SCRIPT}"
  fi
  exec "${EXECUTABLE_SHELL_SCRIPT}" "$@"
}
function main() {
  cp "${EXECUTABLE_SHELL_SCRIPT}" "${EXISTING_SHELL_SCRIPT}"
  # your code here
} 

if [[ $MY_NAME = \.* ]]; then
  # invoke real main program
  trap "clean_up; self_clean_up" EXIT
  main "$@"
else
  # update myself and invoke updated version
  trap clean_up EXIT
  update_self_and_invoke "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is that this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What are you *really* trying to achieve?

That said, your success with this depends on exactly what interpreter you're using.  While you've tagged your question `bash`, you're executing the script as `#!/bin/sh`.

When I run your test using bash, I get similar results.  But when I run it using `/bin/sh` that comes with FreeBSD, I get something that looks more like success:

```
0 ghoti@pc:~/tmp 6> ./exectest.sh
a1
a2
b1
b2
b3
a3
0 ghoti@pc:~/tmp 7>
```

Remember that the purpose of [`exec`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=exec&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) is to "replace" the current process image with a new process image.  The behaviour of the `exec` shell command in **bash** is to "replace the shell", according to the man page.

I think you'll have the best results if you don't try to replace the script that's *actually running*.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "A1 - $0"
sleep 1
echo "A2"
sleep 1
me=$(basename $0); me=A-${me##?-}
tr 'AB' 'BA' < $0 > $me
chmod +x $me
exec ./$me
echo "A3"
sleep 1
```

... which for me gives the following repeating results:

```
0 ghoti@pc:~/tmp 17> ./exectest.sh
A1 - ./exectest.sh
A2
B1 - /home/ghoti/tmp/A-exectest.sh
B2
A1 - /home/ghoti/tmp/B-exectest.sh
A2
B1 - /home/ghoti/tmp/A-exectest.sh
B2
A1 - /home/ghoti/tmp/B-exectest.sh
^C
1 ghoti@pc:~/tmp 18>
```

This bounces back and forth between A and B scripts, never reaching A3 because each script is executed *from the beginning* rather than from the offset within the script that you're overwriting.

Is that what you're looking for?